# Complex xPath query with getNodeSet in R

Tags: xml, r, xpath

I have the following xml file downloaded from Uniprot protein database.

```
protein <- xmlRoot(xmlTreeParse("http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q01974.xml"))
```

From the numerous annotated features, I am interested in the start and end position of the kinase domain stored in the following xml node:

```
<feature type="domain" description="Protein kinase">
<location>
<begin position="288"/>
<end position="539"/>
</location>
</feature>
```

With the getNodeSet I could nicely locate this tag:

```
getNodeSet(protein, "//uniprot:feature[@type=\"domain\" and @description=\"Protein kinase\"]", c(uniprot="http://uniprot.org/uniprot"))
```

Unfortunately I could not narrow down the query, addition of any other criteria returns an empty list. Example:

```
getNodeSet(protein, "//uniprot:feature[@type=\"domain\" and @description=\"Protein kinase\"]/location", c(uniprot="http://uniprot.org/uniprot"))
```

Based on an online xpath tester, that should be valid xpath query, but returns empty:

```
list()
attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

Could anyone help me please with this query?
I am sure this is a normal behavior of getNodeSet, but I don't know what is the rational behind it.
In general, what is the most appropriate way to phrase such relatively complicated queries in R? Should I store the result and then further narrow down?

Thank you very much!

Comment: use the same prefix for subsequent element as well : `//uniprot:feature[...]/uniprot:location` ?

Comment: Works. Amazing. Thank you! But why should the namespace prefix be added again?

Comment: tried to explain in my answer, check it out

Comment: Just a comment on Uniprot for those interested...  Check the FAQ at http://www.uniprot.org/faq/28, but there are lots of ways to access data.  You could also try the gff file http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q01974.gff or use a restful query like http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?format=tab&query=accession:Q01974&columns=id,feature%28DOMAIN_EXTENT%29

Comment: Thanks Chris! I did not know you can retrieve just pieces of the annotation! (At this time I intentionally downloaded the entries in xml, just to get some exposure to this data format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the same prefix for subsequent element as well :

```
//uniprot:feature[...]/uniprot:location
```

`prefix + local-name` identify each element. In case you have XML with default namespace (seems this is what you have), all element without prefix considered in default namespace. That's the reason why you need to use *the prefix** for each element in XPath (not only the first element).

*) *the prefix* that points to default namespace URI

Comment: Nice explantion. OP can simplify expression also `getNodeSet(protein, "//ns:feature[@type=\"domain\" and @description=\"Protein kinase\"]", "ns")` and `getNodeSet(protein, "//ns:feature[@type=\"domain\" and @description=\"Protein kinase\"]/ns:location", "ns")` respectively